# Some website images don't work?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, caching

http://astrobri.com/ - for this website there are some images that don't work.
Is a wordpress website and for cache I use WP Fastest Cache with this settings and this .htaccess rule:

```
# Image and Flash content Caching for One Month
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Could it be this rule?
Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: add in style.css .post img { opacity: 1 !important;}

Comment: I'm voting to put this question on hold. However, if you can remove the link and illustrate the problem **in the question itself** then I will retract that vote. Remember that we want questions here to make sense even after the problem is fixed - in this case as soon as you fix the website the question may as well be deleted.

Comment: Tags:black, white, one-column, two-columns, fixed-layout

*/



.wpb_row, .wpb_content_element, ul.wpb_thumbnails-fluid > li, .last_toggle_el_margin, .wpb_button {

  margin-bottom: 0;

}



.meta-info .td-post-author-name, .td-module-meta-info .td-post-author-name {

  display: none;

}



.td-pb-row {

  margin-left: 0 !important;

}

Comment: above I've put my style.css content..could you tell me exactly where should I have to put: post img { opacity: 1 !important;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by disabling "Combine JS" option of WP Fastest Cache plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The images are in fact loading. CSS prevents them from beeing visible. Maybe a script that performs animation on the images is not loading correctly.

A workaround is proposed by @vrajesh already:

```
.post img {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Add this to `style.css` to make the images visble.